# SFINAE member variable

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I have quite a lot of templates that look like this:

```
template <int n>
struct MyClass
{
    Property p;
    MyClass<n - 1> next;
};

template <>
struct MyClass<1>
{
    Property p;
};
```

Basically MyClass contains n properties.

I was wondering if this could be done in a nicer way. An example would be that I only want `next` if `n>1`.

Comment: `MyClass` doesn't contain `n` properties, you spawn `n` different classes that are composited with each other to make a list. A vector or list of properties would be easier. Unless there's a reason for the SFINAE that's not shown.

Comment: For templates, this reads pretty clearly to me. Maybe you want a variable-sized tuple of properties instead?

Comment: A `std::array<Property, n>` appears a much easier alternative to your approach.